# Alternatives to window.scrollMaxY?

Tags: javascript, android, webkit

I' trying to use *window.pageYOffset* & *window.scrollMaxY* to calculate the current page progress. This approach works under FF3.5 but under webkit *window.scrollMaxY* is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got away with `document.body.scrollHeight` so that

```
document.body.scrollHeight = window.pageYOffset + screen height in pixels
```

at the end of the page (on Android).

Answer (score 20):

Alternative to `window.scrollMaxY`:

```
document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight
```

gives same result as `window.scrollMaxY` with ie7, ie8, ff3.5, Safari 4, Opera 10, Google Chrome 3 under DOCTYPE XHTML 1.0 Transitional.

Comment: Thank you good sir.  I'd love to know if there's any downsides to using this method. I just tested it in chrome/firefox and it works!

Comment: Trying to implement it against `window.scrollY` I noticed that in chrome at least, `window.scrollY` is an high-precision float, while `scrollHeight` and `clientHeight` are integers, so I had to `Math.round()` it

Answer (score 4):

two years later...

```
function getScrollMaxY(){"use strict";
    var innerh = window.innerHeight || ebody.clientHeight, yWithScroll = 0;

    if (window.innerHeight && window.scrollMaxY){
        // Firefox 
        yWithScroll = window.innerHeight + window.scrollMaxY; 
    } else if (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight){ 
        // all but Explorer Mac 
        yWithScroll = document.body.scrollHeight; 
    } else { 
        // works in Explorer 6 Strict, Mozilla (not FF) and Safari 
        yWithScroll = document.body.offsetHeight; 
    } 
    return yWithScroll-innerh; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 x = document.body.clientHeight;
 console.log(x ,"Cline HEight");     

 xx = window.innerHeight;
 console.log(xx, "Inner Height");

 xxx = document.body.scrollHeight
 console.log(xxx, "scrollHeight");

 xxxx = window.scrollMaxY; 
 console.log(xxxx, "scrollMaxY for IE");


 xxxxx = document.body.offsetHeight;
 console.log(xxxxx, "offsetHeight");

 xxxxxx= document.body.scrollTop;
 console.log(xxxxxx, "scrollTop");strong text
```