# Why does window.scrollMaxY incorrectly returns zero in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, window, scroll

I'm trying to write some code that scrolls the page to an element and then adjusts the scroll position to take into account a header with `position: fixed`.

It seems that the most sensible way to do this is to use something along the lines of

```
var element = document.getElementById('myElement');
element.scrollIntoView();
if(window.scrollY < window.scrollMaxY)
    window.scroll(0,window.scrollY - 50);
```

At first this seemed to work. I don't know what has just changed, but for some reason now `window.scrollMaxY` has just started returning 0 even where there is clearly a scrollbar and it should not be zero.

Answer (score 0):

Before I'd even finished posting the question I realised what the problem was when I was thinking about alternative solutions.

Knowing that window.scrollMaxY isn't supported by WebKit yet, I had found https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732727/990262 and based on that had created my own polyfill as follows which was at the top of my Javascript file.

```
/* For webkit and any other browser that doesn't have scrollMaxY */
if(!window.scrollMaxY) window.scrollMaxY = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

Because most of the content is loaded by AJAX, at the point when the page was loaded, the value of scrollMaxY was zero, which evaluted to false and caused this code to replace the real value with the result of that calculation, which also turned out to be zero.

The solution would be to modify the polyfill so that the test is more specific e.g. `if 'scrollMaxY' in window)` rather than `if(!window.scrollMaxY)` and wrap the assigned value in a function.