# How can I handle when js calls the scrollMaxY param withTypescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am converting code from javascript to Typescript running on modern browsers. I am using the VS2013 IDE and I am getting no IDE errors except for in one place where the code tries to reference scrollMayY.

```
position.getPageSize = function () {

    var scrollWidth, scrollHeight;
    var innerWidth, innerHeight;

    // It's not very clear which blocks work with which browsers.
    if (self.innerHeight && self.scrollMaxY) {
        scrollWidth = doc.body.scrollWidth;
        scrollHeight = self.innerHeight + self.scrollMaxY;
    }
    else if (doc.body.scrollHeight > doc.body.offsetHeight) {
        scrollWidth = doc.body.scrollWidth;
        scrollHeight = doc.body.scrollHeight;
    }
    else {
        scrollWidth = doc.body.offsetWidth;
        scrollHeight = doc.body.offsetHeight;
    }
```

Here I am getting an error saying: the property scrollMaxY does not exist on object of type Window.

Can anyone give me any suggestions on how I should deal with this. I am not sure if it's an error with the code or if I need to do something different with Typescript to avoid this check? Note the comment in the code is not by me. It was by the developer of the code.

Comment: ` I am not sure if it's an error with the code or if I need to do something different with Typescript to avoid this check?` Experimental / Unstable APIs are not a part of `lib.d.ts`. You only get ambient definitions for stable API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define `scrollMaxY` on `window`:

```
interface Window { scrollMaxY: number; }
```

...which would remove your compile time error.

Or do:

```
self["scrollMaxY"]
```

Or you could look for some [alternatives to `window.scrollMaxY`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091048/alternatives-to-window-scrollmaxy)